# NSFetchedResultsController not properly updating tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data

I'm fetching some items (NSManagedObject) in viewDidLoad, and i'm using the NSFetchedResultsController delegates to update tableView cells in swift ios (the delegates from Apple docs for insertion, deletion etc.), the issue is that when I add an item to core data of the same ManagedObject type, i expect the table to update with the new item, but instead the last item is removed from the tableview and the new one isn't added. I only see the new item when I load the screen again... what could be wrong?
Here is my fetchedResultsController:

```
lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Message> = {
    let context = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let request: NSFetchRequest<Message> = Message.fetchRequest()

    request.sortDescriptors = [
        NSSortDescriptor(key: "createdAt", ascending: true)
    ]
    request.fetchLimit = 40

    let frc = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: context, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

    // fetch only messages with that recipient id of the chat.
    let recipientId = "\(chat!.recipientId)"
    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recipientId == %@", recipientId)

    return frc
}()
```

and here is how i'm creating and adding a new message

```
func createNewTextMessage(recipientId: String, content: String) {

    ...

    guard let id = Int32(recipientId) else { return }
    guard let chat = fetchSingleChat(recipientId: id) else { return }

    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    let message = Message(context: context)

    let date = Date()

    message.chatId = chat.id
    message.createdAt = date
    message.isRead = false
    message.senderId = Int32(currentUserId)
    message.senderName = currentUserName
    message.senderPhoneNumber = currentUserPhoneNumber
    message.status = MessageStatus.unsent.rawValue
    message.type = MessageType.text.rawValue
    message.owner = MessageOwnerType.mine.rawValue
    message.content = content
    message.recipientId = chat.recipientId
    message.recipientName = chat.title

    message.messageId = "\(currentUserToken)_\(date.millisecondsSince1970)"

    // here's where i'm setting some relationship (chat to message: 1-to-many)
    message.chat = chat 
    chat.lastMessage = message
    message.chat?.lastMessage = message

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch let err {
        print("failed to save private chat:", err)
    }

}
```

The chat ManagedObject has an attribute of lastMessage which is of type Message (also a managed object), i set the newly created message to the Chat's last message. Could the problem be from there.
And here is the delegate code as well:

```
// MARK: - NSFetchedResultsController Delegates

func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
    case .move:
        break
    case .update:
        break
    }
}

func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .right)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .update:
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
    case .move:
        tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
    }
}

func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

Comment: *... i'm using the NSFetchedResultsController delegates*. Where do you set the delegate?

Comment: the delegate is set in the viewDidLoad, that's where i do the fetching as well

Comment: Maybe you should show us the delegate code as well.

Comment: i've added the delegate code

Answer (score 0):

Note that your handling of moving rows (.move) only moves one row, you should implement it to move many. Not sure if this solves your problem, it depends on how your data is sorted.

Here is how I have implemented my .move

```
case .move:
    if let indexPath = indexPath {
        tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: indexPath.item), withAnimation: .effectFade)
    }
    if let newIndexPath = newIndexPath {
        tableView.insertRows(at: IndexSet.init(integer: newIndexPath.item), withAnimation: .effectFade)
    }
```

Comment: my sorting was based on a date. besides does sorting trigger a move? cause i was only inserting new items

Comment: Like I said I’m not sure if it solves your issue, maybe you could try it out, but it still an improvement since it handles multiple rows just like your other switch cases. And if it’s not helpful I’ll delete this answer.